# Conjugation of wonder in early modern English

Tags: etymology, early-modern-english

What I actually mean what's the conjugation of the verb *wonder*. For example:

> I wonder, thou wonderest, etc..

including past, ing form, etc.. (it will actually help me with other verbs too)

Comment: Is there something special about 'wonder' that you've noticed is different from the way others verbs are conjugated? If so can you give an example in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Past: wondered, thou wonderedst

Present: I wonder, thou wonderest (rarer: wonderst), he wondereth, we wonder, you wonder, they wonder

Participle: wondering

Comment: how about "Have you been wondering?"
Would it be, "Hast thou been wondering"?

Comment: @user1135588, I think so, or maybe "art thou been wondering" — or something else. Not sure.

Comment: @msh210: "Art thou been [anything]" is gibberish. "Hast wondered?" would have been fine, since "hast" already implies second person singular subject.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so how about "ye" and "them" Is it used like today?

Comment: @user1135588: Erm... we don't use any of those archaic pronouns today. But it would have been *"Hath ye wondered?"*. And *"them"* (which is still current) is the object form, not subject of a verb. Unless you have a *very* good reason for wanting to learn the archaic forms, I really do suggest you steer clear of them and just learn current English!

Comment: @FumbleFingers -  "Hath ye wondered" ??? Really?  Since when does 2nd person plural 'ye' take the third person singular verb 'hath'?  It would be "Have ye wondered?"

Comment: @chasly: Oops! Well, I'll leave my mistake there as testimony to the fact that even (supposedly competent) native speakers can get such matters wrong! :)